# Can't run android app with library project and JNI together

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to run an android app with two relatives:

1. CSipSimple Library project.
2. `.so` libraries loaded using JNI.

When running the app using only the `.so` libraries, it works perfectly, but when running it after adding the CSipSimple project, it can't find the `.so` library and give me the following exception:

09-22 17:18:02.650: W/System.err(13662): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load dvr from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.automation.isolace-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.automation.isolace-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
09-22 17:18:02.650: W/System.err(13662):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
09-22 17:18:02.650: W/System.err(13662):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
09-22 17:18:02.650: W/System.err(13662):    at com.company.NetSDK.INetSDK.LoadLibrarys(INetSDK.java:26)
09-22 17:18:02.650: W/System.err(13662):    at com.company.NetSDK.INetSDK.(INetSDK.java:6)
09-22 17:18:02.650: W/System.err(13662):    at com.automation.isolace.VideoViewActivity$3.run(VideoViewActivity.java:137)

The method **LoadLibraries**:

```
/*    */   public static void LoadLibrarys()
/*    */   {
/*    */     try
/*    */     {
/* 17 */       String strOSType = System.getProperty("os.name");
/* 18 */       if (strOSType.contains("Window"))
/*    */       {
/* 20 */         System.loadLibrary("dhconfigsdk");
/* 21 */         System.loadLibrary("dhnetsdk");
/* 22 */         System.loadLibrary("netsdk");
/*    */       }
/*    */       else
/*    */       {
/* 26 */         System.loadLibrary("dvr");
/* 27 */         System.loadLibrary("configsdk");
/* 28 */         System.loadLibrary("netsdk");
/* 29 */         System.loadLibrary("sdk");
/*    */       }
/*    */     } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ulink) {
/* 32 */       ulink.printStackTrace();
/*    */     }
/*    */   }
```

and the Hierarchy of my app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably because of the libraries in `libs/armeabi` & `libs/armeabi-v7a` are different, such as the `libs/armeabi-v7a` only contains a subset of .so libraries. When you add a library project dependency, you should check its `libs/armeabi` & `libs/armeabi-v7a` folders as well.

Comment: in fact, when running with only libs/armeabi it was running perfectly, so I assumed that the device processor is armeabi which make me didn't add the libraries again in the other folders, but this generated the problem, when adding them to the other folders the problem solved.